# Use a ViewModelWidget inside a StreamBuidler?

Tags: flutter, viewmodel, flutter-web, stacked

I'm trying to use a **ViewModelWidget** inside a **StreamBuilder** (which is already used inside a ViewModelWidget).

It works fine when I use a **StatelessWidget**, passing the **viewModel** in params.

But when I use a **ViewModelWidget**, my **print method** is always returning **false** and the animation doesn't work, even if my **viewModel** seems to get and return the good data.

Did I do something wrong ? Or is it not possible to achieve it like this ?

```dart
    class HoverButton extends ViewModelWidget<AccessDialogViewModel> {
      const HoverButton({Key? key, required this.textKey}) : super(key: key);
    
      final String textKey;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context, AccessDialogViewModel viewModel) {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: viewModel.isHovered,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                ButtonOnHover buttonHovered = snapshot.data as ButtonOnHover;
                if (buttonHovered.key == textKey) {
                  return AlertButton(
                    buttonOnHover: ButtonOnHover(
                        key: textKey, isHovered: buttonHovered.isHovered),
                  );
                } else {
                  return AlertButton(
                    buttonOnHover: ButtonOnHover(key: textKey, isHovered: false),
                  );
                }
              } else {
                return AlertButton(
                    buttonOnHover: ButtonOnHover(key: textKey, isHovered: false),
               );
              }
            });
      }
    
    class AlertButton extends ViewModelWidget<AccessDialogViewModel> {
      const AlertButton(
          {Key? key, required this.buttonOnHover})
          : super(key: key);
    
      final ButtonOnHover buttonOnHover;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context, AccessDialogViewModel viewModel) {
        return MouseRegion(
          onEnter: (e) {
            _sendDataToViewModel(
                viewModel, ButtonOnHover(key: buttonOnHover.key, isHovered: true));
            print(buttonOnHover.isHovered); //==> always returning false
          },
          onExit: (e) {
            _sendDataToViewModel(
                viewModel, ButtonOnHover(key: buttonOnHover.key, isHovered: false));
            print(buttonOnHover.isHovered); //==> always returning false
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 100,
              color: buttonOnHover.isHovered
                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
                  : Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(buttonOnHover.key, TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: this is because `final ButtonOnHover buttonOnHover;` will create a new object and since the default value for isHovered is set to false it is printing false. You can create a service which keeps track of the state and use that in your widgets.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Ashutoshpatole, I'll try it. 
But the state isn't suppose to be save in the ViewModel?

Comment: It should be saved in the viewModel but your ButtonHover is not a viewModel right ?